# Get JSON response value when key is hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used below AJAX call and get the value of Draft. But, getting undefined errors.

Sorry, I am not sure whether hyphen in "application-info" is causing the issue. Can help to guide to solve this issue?

```js
{
   "app-info":[
      {
         "info":{
            "NAME":"John Doe",
            "GENDER":"M",
            "RACE":"US",
         },
         "draft":"004842",
      }
   ],
   "STATUS":"N"
}


var appEndpoint = $('.component').data('fetch-app-endpoint');
fetch(fetchAppEndpoint, {
   method: 'GET'
  })
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(resp => {
    console.log('response', resp);
    console.log('test', resp.app-info[0].draft);
  })
```

Comment: What's an _"undefined error"_?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: The dupe talks about a space, but it's the same for a dash